# Raw clean data without using any tags

Tags: php

how i can raw clean text like this 
view-source:https://www.exploit-db.com/raw/48467
Knowing that I cannot use `strip_tags()` Or `nl2br()`
When I raw it directly without using any tags like `row['data_text']` Fall into the line problem

```php
<?php
  $code_id = (int)$_GET['raw'];
  $sql = "SELECT code_id,code_text FROM codes WHERE `code_id` = '$code_id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $found = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($found >  0 ){ 
    echo $row['code_text'];
  }
?>
```

Is the solution can be in use `file_get_contents('x.txt')` !!!

Comment: Where is the risk and where is the vulnerability? 
Your answer has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Improved Formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, thank you
**header("Content-Type: text/plain");**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$code_id = (int)$_GET['raw'];
$sql = "SELECT code_id,code_text FROM codes WHERE `code_id` = '$code_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$found = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($found >  0 ){ 
echo $row['code_text'];
}
?>
```